# Is there a way to upgrade my laptop's video card to drive two 1920x1200 external displays?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Preferably, one of those displays could be rotated (1200x1920).

Answer (score 1):

Please, provide more information about your computer. However, it is NOT possible usually. The only way I can think of to use the DVI (or DisplayPort/HDMI) AND a VGA/DVI port. (So use two different output ports for the two displays). Maybe you can get a port replicator/dock at the homepage of your laptop's manufacturer. (Like Lenovo's dock replicates your port).

Comment: Dell Latitude 630, intel mobile chipset 965.  I'm looking to avoid an external USB card or splitter box.  Can I just add a better video card?  (Figured this was probably not possible, but worth a try)

Comment: Adding a new card is impossible. You can use the linked Dell Dock above (as I mentioned it in the post). Its impossible to split it like that in a notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at another solution: [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/). It connects to your laptop and to external monitors, and does the work of driving the external displays. Jeff Atwood wrote about [a similar device](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/joining-the-prestigious-three-monitor-club/comments/page/2/) a couple years ago.

I've not used this solution, but a former coworker did, and he said it worked well for him.

Comment: Yeah that's a way to go but I thought its out of the question because it costs a fortune. (But yeah that thing works).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way would be to purchase a Dell D/Dock.  It does only have one DVI port though, so one of your monitors would need to be connected via VGA.

http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/docking_station/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=corp&sku=310-2873

Comment: I already have one of these.  Don't I need a special video card to drive two external displays, though?

Comment: No, your existing video card should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops can handle only one external display.

To connect another one, you can look for an [ExpressCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard) or PC Card graphics adapter (they are rare, see [here](http://www3.shopping.com/xPO-HIS-HIS-Notebook-DVI-Graphics-Card-HVTBOOK-Type-II-PC-Card-Interface-Mail-In-30-00-Expires-07-3)). I'm not sure it's better than a USB box, since due to VGA/DVI connector size it will either have protruding parts or require a non-standard cable (so you'll have to lug around one extra piece anyway).

Comment: Dell D630 has not have an Express Card slot.

Comment: @Paul Obviously, then you'd need a PC card one...